# Weird behaviours with generic intersection type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The title might be a bit off, but I don't know how to describe the problem accurately.

I have the following code:

*global.d.ts*

```
type BuiltInListener<T extends Element, Key extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap> = (event: HTMLElementEventMap[Key], target: T) => any;
type Listener<T extends Element, TDetails = any> = (details: TDetails, target: T, event: EventUnion<TDetails>) => any;
type EventUnion<TDetails> = CustomEvent<TDetails>|HTMLElementEventMap[keyof HTMLElementEventMap];

type FilteredEventMap<TEvents> = keyof Omit<HTMLElementEventMap, keyof TEvents|'options'>;

type EventListenerConfig<T extends Element = Element, TEvents extends object = {}> = {
    options?: Options;
    [key: string]: Listener<T>|Options|undefined;
} & {
    [Key in FilteredEventMap<TEvents>]?: BuiltInListener<T, Key>;
} & {
    [Key in keyof Omit<TEvents, 'options'>]?: Listener<T, TEvents[Key]>;
};

interface EventTarget
{
    on<T extends Element = Element, TEvents extends object = {}>(
        selector: string|EventListenerConfig<T, TEvents>,
        settings?: EventListenerConfig<T, TEvents>
    ): EventTarget;

    trigger(event: string): EventTarget;
    emit<TDetail = any>(event: string, detail?: TDetail, composed?: boolean): CustomEvent<TDetail>;
    await<TDetail = any>(event: string): Promise<TDetail>;
}
```

*Examples*

```
// 1
this.shadow.on({
    options: {
        passive: false,
    },
    wheel: (e) => { // <--- inferred as any
    },
});


// 2
const kaas: EventListenerConfig = {
    options: {
        passive: false,
    },
    wheel: (e) => { // <--- inferred as WheelEvent
    },
};

// 3
this.shadow.on<Element>({
    options: {
        passive: false,
    },
    wheel: (e) => { // <--- inferred as WheelEvent
    },
});


// 4
this.shadow.on<Button, { click: { action: string } }>('footer > [action]', {
    click: ({ action }) => {}, // <--- inferred as { action: string }
    wheel: (e) => {}, // <--- inferred as WheelEvent
});
```

why is it that `1` one gets inferred to `any` but all the other examples do work?

`3` is a copy of `1` where I explicitly set the generic type, but it is the same as the default for that generic type.

`4` is just an example of why I even have this ridiculous set up

To me it almost seems as if the compiler does something funky with default generic parameters, and that's why the `EventListenerConfig` of `1` goes through the `[key: string]` route instead of the `[Key in FilteredEventMap<TEvents>]` route.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEF5K7NAVAmgBQKIGUIyzUIBQALgJ4AOApqAEICuAlgDYECSAdgDK0DOBZLZATgB44oMgA8eLACadQKAG68CcAIb8A5mQIAaUAGkyRURN4zQAa0MB7AGagAEnACybFPTIBbJQqVOVJAD4IUAAKMkUWAgAuB2dXdy9In0i-EgBtAyIAXV0CNU1o+ABKCCCVFiIAbkJSCg5uXgFhY0kzZOV8rV04ABEtFQZZcFByoiDhkKl+wZje6fpOXM7CuF1wpRj2gFUWWisWYT68wYCS8DKK6uJyOQiCHb2DueOF8dAAYWpuKw92w-nOAEAD6OFxuTzeO6pNKWIi2WJghKQ3z+LLVGo3ABiDB4-DIUnaqWE7UBwVh8IA8h5aARBKD4hCklD-LpyXY4CSAujrhR2vVJAJ3vsbLR1M1xK1ZO1VBotMFpctuiSWqZZFYAEYAKzIAGMCMEAN4AXzeBrwoAtoBhhhi3H4tBY6iyMX5jSEcGB1GkZBFfCk1SNoAAZKAzZarZlQA7QNjGAJ8YT-MS7oCsgB+GI0HGsV18d26TJcvCBkNhy0ZQxRlgWazsknpl1cAX5+AkivZItG9EO3E2FQ63l3GUFPBli37cUmaRSofLeWz2U6VsplXT0Aa7V6w0mkLm8OWzhkdx6qz8W0Ee2OoF8ptuoUsEVi1bLpSA7R7-egQ8EAgO9ScDNbiUXNBWFUVhCVFMAg-UAik2BcCgDPA8BATBsCgD4fhIfYlDQ9CsFwYA8B1egVE4WQaB-fZVzaBCtFHGCSGodV6FoHVQCkKw0B+LQAAs-xCIoYLHfdUIARhg8MCH4zgADp9hCETPwtAB3XiyCPGIwjOIIDUI0BBAAWmMqsbAEPEpBGWRRkk5SjXfZTQCNIp0Vsi1UIAJjc0AdX2bgLBUMj4OA2883vR9DW88M1I0+gtLIHTQ30oyTIdMz+AsqzQAAdXUo92iiy17O8rtkMc1CAGZvOkrh5IOBVFwCRTCtUvK4tCBLSiS1CUsM0zzPxLLctigrHPDYrHOc1zyrAAAWaqZLqwRKIIfZdD0ki2PMGI9P7X99nPS91CcpymoAchsKwrFxUAgjSPbHiyM71panzWJ1bbQl2vVHicxLjV0HrjL6tKBsssikoeg6vwvP8nNemLNI6-77OS4H+oywaIeG-K7hKlyYKNYsgA)

Comment: please share reproducable example

Comment: @captain-yossarian added a playground link

Comment: That's quite a lot of code to wade through and type definitions to chase down; do you think you could try to remove everything which isn't needed for reproduction?  The "minimal" in [mcve] helps everyone focus attention on the actual issue.

Comment: @jcalz this is as far as I can reduce it without cause unintended side effects, the only thing I could do now is add comments. but as far as I', concerned the middle block of code can be ignored, it's only there so the code can run, which is irrelevant to my question. As it pertains to the static analysis of the generics.

Comment: Your [mcve] does not really need to run if the runtime behavior is not the problem.  You don't need to use `Options` if your problem is not with `Options`.  The point is to isolate the problem so it can be analyzed and solved.  The solution could then be applied to your full code that needs to run.  While it's nice to have the full code to test the solution, it really gets in the way of actually diagnosing the problem. My guess here is that it's going to be TS's lack of good support for inferring both generic type parameters and unannotated callback params simultaneously, but right now ‍♂️

Comment: @jcalz Stripped it as far down as I can, the problem is still reproducible. stating the obvious, but for clarity's sake, the inferred type is shown when you hover over the callback's parameter.

Comment: Okay, I guess we're at an impasse.  Hopefully someone else will come along who can work with what's here.  Good luck!

Comment: I meant to say I updated the playground the way you suggested

Comment: @jcalz sorry, forgot to tag you in my previous comment

Comment: Yeah, I see it now, thanks.  I'll take a look... you might consider using overloads to get better behavior.  Let me see if I can get something to show you

Comment: Okay, take a look at [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKkEGW).  The idea is that when you are not going to specify the generic type parameters, as in your case 1, (your 2, 3, and 4 examples have them specified either manually or via defaults...) then you want to make contextual type inference as easy as possible on the compiler.  Your original version made it possible that the `wheel` callback could take anything whatsoever.   added an overload that is more restrictive.  If this meets your needs I'll write up an answer.    Otherwise, please clarify what's missing.

Comment: @jcalz that's the weird thing, I'd expect case 1 and 2 to work the same, since they are both specified via defaults. And I sadly still need the [key: string] case as well for the legacy code. I think I figured it out [here](https://tsplay.dev/wj5gbW).  In case 2 the generic get defaulted to `{}` as I'd expect, case 1 however infers the `TEvents` from the passed parameter. is there any way I can force TS to use a generics default instead of inferring it?

Comment: intended behaviour it seems https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19205

Comment: No, that's how generic function calls work; if you don't specify the parameters they get inferred, and only fall back to the default if they cannot be inferred.  You can add an overload though, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgrj6W), so that when you don't specify the type parameters it uses a different overload from the one where you do.  This gives you essentially the same behavior you're asking for, but it's not doing it by "forcing a default".  So, does that meet your needs and make the basis for an acceptable answer?  Or am I missing something else?

Comment: @jcalz Yep that's 100% the behavior I want. I am new to typescript, so I'm still hardwired to think there's no overloading :P so yes, this is exactly what I was looking for, so acceptable answer worthy.

Thank you soooo much for your time :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between your `1` example and your `2`, `3`, and `4` examples is that you are not specifying the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters when you call `on()` in `1`, whereas you are in the others.  Even `2` and `3`, where you do not *manually* specify the type parameters, you are doing so implicitly with the [type parameter defaults](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults).

But for example `1`, you do not specify the type parameters at all, and instead, the compiler *infers* them from the values you pass in for the `selector` and `settings` arguments.  It does not use the type parameter defaults here, unless inference completely fails and it falls back to them.

It looks like the behavior you're looking for is for the compiler not to use type inference at all, and instead use the defaults.  But such type inference is a feature that is desirable most of the time. There's no "turn off inference here" switch you can turn.

---

There is an open suggestion at [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829) to be able to ask the compiler not to infer a type parameter from a particular site where it appears.  Something like `NoInfer<T>` would mean "this is `T`, but don't use a value of type `NoInfer<T>` to infer `T`".  If that feature were implemented, you could change

```
on<T extends EventTarget = EventTarget, TEvents extends object = {}>(
    selector: string | EventListenerConfig<T, TEvents>,
    settings?: EventListenerConfig<T, TEvents>
): EventListenerConfig<T, TEvents>;
```

to

```
on<T extends EventTarget = EventTarget, TEvents extends object = {}>(
    selector: string | EventListenerConfig<T, NoInfer<TEvents>>,
    settings?: EventListenerConfig<T, NoInfer<TEvents>>
): EventListenerConfig<T, TEvents>;
```

and things would behave better for you, at least for the `TEvents` type parameter.  And while it turns out that there are some ways to define `NoInfer<T>` that work for some use cases (such as [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546)), there's no official version of it, and even if there were, this feature is geared more toward *selective* inference and not complete disabling of it.

---

Instead, my suggestion here would be to add an [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) of the `on()` method, with a more restrictive call signature in which the `TEvents` type parameter simply does not exist.  Anywhere `TEvents` appeared previously, you'd use the default `{}`:

```
interface EventTarget {

    on<T extends EventTarget = EventTarget>(
        selector: string | EventListenerConfig<T, {}>,
        settings?: EventListenerConfig<T, {}>
    ): EventListenerConfig<T, {}>;

    on<T extends EventTarget, TEvents extends object = {}>(
        selector: string | EventListenerConfig<T, TEvents>,
        settings?: EventListenerConfig<T, TEvents>
    ): EventListenerConfig<T, TEvents>;
}
```

The previous signature is still there as a second overload (although I removed the default on `T` because it's not necessary anymore; if you want the default for `T`, then you also want it for `TEvents`, in which case you want the first call signature).

So now, when you call `on()` without specifying type parameters, the first thing the compiler will do is try to use that first overload.  It will only move onto the second overload if that fails.  You can verify that this makes things behave better for your `1` example:

```
    const ok = this.on({
        wheel: (e) => { }, // <--- inferred as WheelEvent
    });
```

while not affecting the behavior for your `2`, `3`, and `4` examples:

```
    // 2
    const kaas: EventListenerConfig = {
        wheel: (e) => { }, // <--- inferred as WheelEvent
    };

    // 3
    this.on<EventTarget>({
        wheel: (e) => { }, // <--- inferred as WheelEvent
    });


    // 4
    this.on<Button, { click: { action: string } }>('footer > [action]', {
        click: ({ action }) => { }, // <--- inferred as { action: string }
        wheel: (e) => { }, // <--- inferred as WheelEvent
    });
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEF5K7NAVAmgBQKIGUIyzUIBQALgJ4AOApqAEICuAlgDYECSAdgDK0DOBZLZATgB44oMgA8eLACadQKAG68CcAIb8A5mQIAaUAGkyRURN4zQAa0MB7AGagAEnACybFPTIBbJQqVOVJAD4IUAAKMkUWAgAuB2dXdy9In0i-EgBtAyIAXV0CNU1o+ABKCCCVFiIAbkJSCg5uXgFhY0kzZOV8rV04ABEtFQZZcFByoiDhkKl+wZje6fpOXM7CuF1wpRj2gFUWWisWYT68wYCS8DKK6uJyOQiCHb2DueOF8dAAYWpuKw92w-nOEEAD6xFxuTzeO6pNKWIi2UHxCFJKH+LLVGo3ABiDB4-DIUnaqWE7UBwVh8IA8h5aARBI4wQlIb5-LpyXY4CSAujrhR2vVJAJ3vsbLR1M1xK1ZO1VBotMFpctuiSWqZZFYAEYAKzIAGMCMEAN4AXzeBrwoAtoBhhhi3H4tBY6iyMX5jSEcGBoGo0jIIr4UmqRtAADJQGbLRGrZlQA7QNjGAJ8YT-MS7oCsgB+GI0HGsV18d26TJc82WoOh8ORi0ZQwxlgWazskmZl1cAWF+AkmvZEsRo3oh24mwqHUUCn0Al3GUFMOli37cUmaRSqfLeWr2U6TtplXL0Aa7V6w0mkJzyOcMjuPVWfi2gj2x2gEF8ttuoUsEVi1bbpSA7RniMLwIAgHXUTgs1uJR80FYVRWEJU0wCM8ik2O5oP4d9P3gn9IkBQM8DwQcBGHUdIMiac5TNM8FxECVVTIjpN3XJQKIIAJTyrC0LyvAgbzvB91CfBj0MwuDv2NAJ-040AgJAx1wNQqDXwLUSv10CTkMUyIRNgtSwxNdEIxo3c2g3AoEN-Ey1S1XV9WGCSOM47jbL4mT71AoSXwaFTdOwjlEKkpytDksCIK89tVL8zlNOE5SYI-MSLNwksjQIkBMGwKAPh+Eh9iUDLMqwXBgDwHV6BUThZBoYD9ishjWNnCMSGodV6FoHVQCkKw0B+LQAAtQJCEpKyrdKAEYAMtHV9m4fdzGCAgBs4AA6fYQhG6TQAAdz6shLxiMIziCA1QCNXR0sEABaa66xsAQ8SkEZZAAdV2y92kmi0jSKdFPuK0AACY-umlhZvMFQKq0ggdISwT7L+iMdr2+gDrII6w1O86wCum6HTu-gHqe0BXuRj7pP7AjpPSgBmP7Fq4VaDgVTd2I26Skf20I0dKDGzv+nHLtu+78SJkn3ruP7vt+qmwAAFjppbGcEareJYdTQDK9rzBiE6RxA-Z+I8oMTwAchsKwrFxUAgjSPXHiyE31IRqa2p1bXQl1vVHlO9GTr5i7rsFvHhceiqMbtg23IE07nYtDmUa533Mf5wOhYJkWw7F+gyc4qWz1So0gA)